# Find the area of triangle ABC given area of a subtriangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, area

I'm stuck with this question:

Given the lines in triangles and the intersection point, I thought there could be some implications from those info. My intuition tells me $\Delta ANP=12$ and $\Delta NBC=24$, but could that be true? I find no theorems and properties to back that up.

I attempted Pick's Theorem, though. However, the calculation didn't turn out well.
[image: Problem enclosed in this picture]

Comment: Can you please tell what is " Pick's theorem"?

Comment: Pick's Theorem states that if a polygon has vertices with integer coordinates (lattice points) then the area of the polygon is i+12p−1, where i is the number of lattice points inside the polygon and p is the number of lattice points on the perimeter of the polygon.

Answer (score 3):

We see that $CM:MB=2:1$ and $CN=NA$.

Let $L$ be a mid-point of $CM$.

Thus, $CL=LM=MB$ and $CN||AM$, which gives $$BP:PN=BM:ML=1:1,$$
which says $$S_{\Delta ANB}=2S_{\Delta APB}=24$$ and we obtain:
$$S_{\Delta ABC}=48.$$

Comment: I'm sorry if it sound silly... Can we take CM:MB = 2:1 and CN = NA for granted, or is there a specific way of verifying that?

Comment: @Rons  It follows from the Thales's theorem. In the first case take the rectangle with a diagonal $BC$. In the second case take the rectangle with a diagonal $AC$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\triangle ACM$ and a traversal line crosses its sides at points $B, P$ and $N$. Applying Menelaus's theorem,

$\frac{CB}{BM} \cdot \frac{MP}{PA} \cdot \frac{AN}{NC} = - 1$

That gives $AP = 3 ~MP$

So, $S_{\triangle APB} = \frac{3}{4} S_{\triangle AMB} = \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{3} S_{\triangle ABC} = 12$

$\implies S_{\triangle ABC} = 48$